# Вытащить маcсив из переменной PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть переменная в которой лежат массивы, как мне обратиться именно к 1 массиву.
Пример:

```
[
    [0 => '<url>'], 
    [0 => '<url>'] 
]
```

Comment: Чем плохо $arr[0]?

Comment: Также current($arr)  Для тестов используйте var_dump($var);

Comment: Если Вы будете использовать `foreach` то получите вложенные массивы в порядке их добавления в переменную.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = Array ( 
    Array ( [0] => http://www.edimdoma.ru/retsepty/81670-konverty-iz-sloenogo-testa-s-tvorogom-i-dzhemom ), 
    Array ( [0] => http://www.edimdoma.ru/retsepty/81670-konverty-iz-sloenogo-testa-s-tvorogom-i-dzhemom ) 
);
var_dump($array[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратитесь к элементам массива следующим образом:

```
<?php


    $array = [
        [1, 2 ,3], //array1
        [4, 5, 6] //array2
    ];

    //обращение к вложенным маccивам
    $array1 = $array[0];
    $array2 = $array[1];

    //обращение к элементам вложенных массивовж
    echo $array[0][0]."<br>"; //return 1
    echo $array[0][2]."<br>"; //return 3
    echo $array[1][0]."<br>"; //return 4
    echo $array[1][2]."<br>"; //return 6
```